# jqGrid How to get the default sort back?

Tags: javascript, sorting, jqgrid

Simple question so I'll keep it brief:

With sorting enabled on a column, the user can click the column header and sort that column in either ascending or descending order.  Is there any way to have an option for "default" or "original" sort order?

They can mimic this behavior by successfully guessing what the default column sort order was and clicking on that column in the correct order (an exposed ID field, for example), but it seems counter-intuitive to not have a "default" order available...

Comment: So you already have a column that is sorted by default, bringing  back the original order?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the option `sortname: ""`, which is default by the way. You can set it per `setGridParam` and trigger `reloadGrid`.